# Omxplayer not always starting with rc.local

Tags: hdmi, video, omxplayer, cec-client

I have trouble with my Raspberry Pi 4B configuration. I prepared RPI to work with TV - it turns on the TV and switches active source to HDMI1 with cec-client. After turning on the TV it should start playing the video with omxplayer, what randomly fails and the omxplayer doesn't start at all.

Here is how it looks:

rc.local:

```
/home/pi/startup.sh
/home/pi/video.sh
exit 0
```

startup.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "on 0.0.0.0" | cec-client -s -d 1
echo "as" | cec-client -s -d 1 -p 1
```

video.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
omxplayer -o hdmi --loop /home/pi/Downloads/video
```

The startup.sh script seems to be fine - TV always starts and the active source is set as it should be. I tried to put "&" sign at the end of the line with path to video.sh script in rc.local file but this didn't help. Also, I set chmod 777 to all video.sh, startup.sh and video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you still use deprecated `/etc/rc.local`.

Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

In particular you should note the last sentence of the document:

> Note that there are some areas where systemd currently provides a certain amount of compatibility where we expect this compatibility to be removed eventually.

It seems that this is the case with the latest Raspberry Pi OS. You should use a systemd Unit file to start your scripts. You will find many examples here on this site with tag [systemd-startup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:79866+%5Bsystemd-startup%5D).

Comment: Thank you! I tested your solution with almost 30 different RPIs and everything works perfectly for now.